# disable responsive on kube css framework

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, css-frameworks, kube-css

I am using [kube](http://imperavi.com/kube) css framework to develop the front end of my site, but I want to disable the responsive feature that this framework is providing by default. I want to do that in few simple lines (`css` or `js`). maybe fixing the width of the body and scrolling the inner divs?

any hints?

**EDIT**

one possible simple solution is to provide this css code

```
body{
    width:1024px !important;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

but I want everything to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

that's the final solution to what I want.

```
@media(min-width:1024px){
    body{
        width:100% !important;
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
    }
}
@media(max-width:1023px){
    body{
        width:1023px !important;
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
    }
}
```